# "As they are referred" vs. "As they appear" when we discuss terms and their definitions

Tags: writing-style, tech-writing, heading

I have a technical document that starts with an introduction section describing the key terms that are used in the document.

What is the proper way to name this section?

- Path component names as they are referred in this document
- Path component names as they appear in this document

(I cannot name it just "Path components names" because there are many different conventions already.)

Comment: ' ... as they are referenced in ...' But I'd use 'used'.

Comment: How about "Definitions of path component names used in this document"?

Comment: Thank you all, Edwin, Weather Vane, and Yosef. I like all the versions.

Comment: @YosefBaskin **MODERATOR NOTE:** Please place answers in the answer box where they belong, *not* in the comment box where they do not. Thank you for your coöperation in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A technical document is one that sets out technical matters. The words and phrases that are used may appear to have meanings in terms of conventional English usage but to assume that these meanings apply within the limited scope of the document is to lead to confusion and error. To take only a handful of examples: pressure, momentum, impulse, energy and force are all words that may be found in dictionaries with meanings much looser and more varied than those required in a technical document describing the ballistics of rifle bullets.

If a technical document is to fulfil its function of describing processes, devices and uses of technical matters, it best starts with a definition of the terms and the way they are to be interpreted within the document, thereby excluding misunderstandings arising from the more common and wider meanings.

I therefore suggest that the section is best titled “Definition of Terms”. Your question is a little ambiguous between *terms* and *names*, so you may prefer “Definition of Path Component Names”.

Comment: "Definition of Path Component Names" is definitely better :)

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with the phrase “path component names” so approached the question from the more general perspective of words and “terms” before mapping the answer back onto your specific phrase.

Answer (score 1):

The standard in technical IT writing is **Naming Conventions for Path Components**.

Also, **Path Component Naming Conventions**.

> [Naming Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming))

Your reader is already in *this document* and doesn't need to hear that you are addressing *this document*.